# Python - Earth Movers Distance

Tags: python, image, image-processing, scipy

I want to use the Earth Movers Distance to compare multiple images.
I compared `scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance()` with `pyemd.emd_samples()`.
As far as I understood the `wasserstein_distance()` takes two distributions, i.e. histograms, while the `emd_samples()` takes an 1D array of values and calculates the histograms for you.
Given that both methods use the same histograms, they should provide the same or at least similar results.
The problem is, that both methods provide highly different results. But, if I pass a flattened version of my images in both methods, the results are very similar.

Is there a mistake on my side or is there a problem with one of these implementations?

```
cat1 = skimage.io.imread("./cat1.jpg", as_grey=True).flatten().astype('float64')
cat2 = skimage.io.imread("./cat2.jpg", as_grey=True).flatten().astype('float64')
shuttle = skimage.io.imread("./shuttle.jpg", as_grey=True).flatten().astype('float64')

emd_s = np.array([[emd_samples(cat1, cat1, bins="fd"), emd_samples(cat1, cat2, bins="fd"), emd_samples(cat1, shuttle, bins="fd")],
                  [emd_samples(cat2, cat1, bins="fd"), emd_samples(cat2, cat2, bins="fd"), emd_samples(cat2, shuttle, bins="fd")],
                  [emd_samples(shuttle, cat1, bins="fd"), emd_samples(shuttle, cat2, bins="fd"), emd_samples(shuttle, shuttle, bins="fd")]])

pmf_cat1, bins_cat1 = np.histogram(cat1 , bins="fd")
pmf_cat2, bins_cat2 = np.histogram(cat2 , bins="fd")
pmf_shuttle, bins_shuttle = np.histogram(shuttle , bins="fd")

emd_s2 = np.array([[emd_samples(pmf_cat1, pmf_cat1, bins="fd"), emd_samples(pmf_cat1, pmf_cat2, bins="fd"), emd_samples(pmf_cat1, pmf_shuttle, bins="fd")],
                  [emd_samples(pmf_cat2, pmf_cat1, bins="fd"), emd_samples(pmf_cat2, pmf_cat2, bins="fd"), emd_samples(pmf_cat2, pmf_shuttle, bins="fd")],
                  [emd_samples(pmf_shuttle, pmf_cat1, bins="fd"), emd_samples(pmf_shuttle, pmf_cat2, bins="fd"), emd_samples(pmf_shuttle, pmf_shuttle, bins="fd")]])

swd = np.array([[wasserstein_distance(pmf_cat1, pmf_cat1), wasserstein_distance(pmf_cat1, pmf_cat2), wasserstein_distance(pmf_cat1, pmf_shuttle)],
                [wasserstein_distance(pmf_cat2, pmf_cat1), wasserstein_distance(pmf_cat2, pmf_cat2), wasserstein_distance(pmf_cat2, pmf_shuttle)],
                [wasserstein_distance(pmf_shuttle, pmf_cat1), wasserstein_distance(pmf_shuttle, pmf_cat2), wasserstein_distance(pmf_shuttle, pmf_shuttle)]])

swd2 = np.array([[wasserstein_distance(cat1, cat1), wasserstein_distance(cat1, cat2), wasserstein_distance(cat1, shuttle)],
                [wasserstein_distance(cat2, cat1), wasserstein_distance(cat2, cat2), wasserstein_distance(cat2, shuttle)],
                [wasserstein_distance(shuttle, cat1), wasserstein_distance(shuttle, cat2), wasserstein_distance(shuttle, shuttle)]])
```

The above example results in similar results for `emd_s` and `swd2` and somehow similar results for `emd_s2` and `swd`, although the last pair is still quite different because technically `emd_samples` should make a histogram based on histograms in this case.

Comment: Please show how you call both functions (note: [minimal, complete, and verifyable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: @Xenthor where does `emd_samples()` come from?

Comment: This project https://github.com/wmayner/pyemd

Answer (score 2):

I came across a similar problem and like to note a couple of things here.

1. Both function `emd_samples` and `wasserstein_distance` take the values observed in an (empirical) distribution as input and NOT the distribution itself.
2. The function `emd` allows you to pass distributions, however, you need to provide the metric as an additional parameter. Also, when working with histograms as (density) distributions you need to normalize them.
3. Not flattening the grey-scale images means that you compare 2D-histgramms which only works with `pyemd`.

Example usage:

```
import numpy as np
import skimage
import os

from pyemd import emd, emd_samples
from scipy.stats import wasserstein_distance

# get some test images
img1 = skimage.io.imread(os.path.join(skimage.data_dir, 'astronaut.png'))
img2 = skimage.io.imread(os.path.join(skimage.data_dir, 'camera.png'))
img3 = skimage.io.imread(os.path.join(skimage.data_dir, 'horse.png'))

# flatten them
images = [img.ravel() for img in [img1, img2, img3]]

# compute EMD using values
emd_samples(images[0], images[1]) # 25.57794401220945
wasserstein_distance(images[0], images[1]) # 25.76187896728515

# compute EMD using distributions
N_BINS = 256
hists = [np.histogram(img, N_BINS, density=True)[0].astype(np.float64) for img in images]

mgrid = np.meshgrid(np.arange(N_BINS), np.arange(N_BINS))
metric = np.abs(mgrid[0] - mgrid[1]).astype(np.float64)

emd(hists[0], hists[1], metric) # 25.862491463680065
```